# How to retrieve Firebase Realtime Database data by userid in a nested viewpager?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-viewpager2

I have two adapter:
One vertical and other horizontal
I would like to put data of an user in the list, so when I swipe horizontal I get just data of this user.

...

```
When I swipe vertical I would like to get another user
Like this:
Vertical swipe
User1 horizontal swipe -> {datauser1, datauser1}
Vertical swipe
User2 horizontal swipe ->   {datauser2, datauser2}
...
```

I have a list with all users Id that I would like to retrieve data from when swipe left (horizontal)
But the problem is that when I swipe vertical I get always the same list with data from all users Id that I have in the list.
That's mean I get:

```
Vertical swipe
User1 horizontal swipe -> {datauser1, datauser1, datauser2, datauser2}
Vertical swipe
User1 horizontal swipe -> {datauser1, datauser1, datauser2, datauser2}
```

My approch to the problem was to get first the id's of the users and then iterate through the array with id's to get data from each userid in the array.
Vertical swipe load list of userid
Horizontal load JUST data from this user id

But it still doesn't work as I want to.

```
public class discover_fullscreen_adapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

private final int stories = 0;
private List<String> userList;
private Context mContext;
private List<Object> objectItems = new ArrayList<>();
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

public discover_fullscreen_adapter2(Context context, List<String> userIdList) {
    this.mContext = context;
    userList = userIdList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    int layout = 0;
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    // Identify viewType returned by getItemViewType(...)
    // and return ViewHolder Accordingly
    if (viewType == stories) {
        layout = R.layout.view_pager_horizontal;
        View contentView = LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(layout, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new testViewHolder2(contentView);
    } else {
        viewHolder = null;
    }
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int viewType = holder.getItemViewType();
    if (viewType == stories) {
        ((testViewHolder2) holder).setViewPager2(((testViewHolder2) holder).videosViewPager, userList);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return userList.size();
}

public class testViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ViewPager2 videosViewPager;
    int limit = 7, itemPos = 0;
    private int currentPage = 0, intttt;
    private int itemCurrentPositionOnViewPager;
    private boolean loading = true;


    public testViewHolder2(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        videosViewPager = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerVideosHorizontal);

    }

    void setViewPager2(ViewPager2 videosViewPager, List<String> listUserId){

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("stories");
        Query queryFeed = databaseReference;
        queryFeed.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                story_modell story = dataSnapshot.getValue(story_modell.class);

                for (String id: listUserId){
                    if (id.equals(story.getUID())){

                        objectItems.add(story);
                    }

                }

                videosViewPager.setAdapter(new view_page_horizontal_adapter(mContext, objectItems));

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it display or there is no display at all ?

Comment: It does display, bvut the problem is that it repeat in ever swipe the same elements @TicherhazFreePalestine

Comment: Can you try to use this `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead `addChildEventListener`?

Comment: Thank you I will try it. @TicherhazFreePalestine

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesnt work @TicherhazFreePalestine